# How is a physical address generated in 8086?

Tags: x86-16, memory-address, microprocessors

In the *8086* architecture, the memory space is 1 MiB in size and divided into logical segments of up to 64 KiB each.

i.e. it has **20** address lines thus the following method is used:

> That the data segment register is shifted left 4 bits then added to the offset register

My question is: How we do the shift operation although all the registers are only 16 bits

Comment: Not really a programming question - this is just CPU architecture (circa mid 1980s) - the "shift" is handled by the CPU hardware - you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: well, it's a programming question, but the premise is wrong.

Comment: @Paul: you are right, but I study the CPU hardware and I didn't see any 20 bit register

Comment: you don't *need* a 20 bit register - the memory interface logic handles the generation of a 20 bit physical address

Comment: can I conclude that it's a memory interface issue

Comment: I wouldn't expect to see a 20-bit *register*; linear addresses aren't stored anywhere, they're just calculated and used.  If you were looking at an 8086 circuit diagram (extremely low level), I assume you'd see a 20-bit adder.  Possibly the same adder that's used for `add` instructions, but `add` only uses the low 16 bits of the result plus the carry-out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Address translation is done internally by a special unit without using the registers available to user code to store intermediate results - it just fetches 16-bit values and does the translation inside - it is not reflected anywhere where the user code could observe it.

Comment: OK, but I need a reference to verify the answer

Comment: @Mina Fouad: No explicit references I'm aware of, but it can be deduced. Registers available to the code are not altered during the translation, so obviously they are not used as intermediate storage for shifts.

Comment: @Mina if you did find the reference, please post it for completeness

Comment: @belisarius: I didn't find but, when I asked the subject's DR the same question, she answered the same as sharptooth.