# If the CS register of a 8086 has the value 0xA000, what is the range of the physical addresses of the associated segment?

Tags: memory, memory-address, cpu-registers, x86-16, segment

As the title already says, I want to know what the range of the physical addresses of the associated segment is, if the CS register of a 8086 has the value 0xA000?

Comment: Why do I get downvotes, it's a reasonable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shift left 4 bits.

0xa0000 + whatever value is hqving CS applied.

Since the cpu registers and other values are 16-bit, you get 0xAxxxx where xxxx is a 16 bit value.  That is, the segment register specifies which 64k can be addressed.  By windowing like that, you can get a 20-bit physical addresss space.

See [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203921/how-is-a-physical-address-generated-in-8086?rq=1) for more info.  Once upon a time that was common teaching, but I suppose now it's harder to find. Maybe you can find some old books via Amazon Marketplace.

Comment: Sorry, I changed my question, what I actually need is the range of the physical addresses of the associated segment. BTW where does the value/offset come from?

Comment: The range addressable is 64K.  The offset is whatever you are doing that implies the CS base.  E.g. a jump to an absolute address.

Answer (score 0):

After a little research I found that this is the correct answer to the question:

0xA0000 + 0xFFFF = 0xAFFFF (highest physical address of the segment)

0xA0000 + 0x0000 = 0xA0000 (lowest physical address of the segment)

So the range of the physical addresses is 0xA0000 - 0xAFFFF.