# How is 16 bit data stored in 20 bit address in Intel 8086 CPU?

Tags: intel, x86-16, 16-bit, microprocessors

In [Intel 8086](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8086), we have **20 bit** address bus so we have *2^(20)* locations. 
I am confused on how this **16 bit** data is stored in **20 bit** address.

### Example:

If I want to store `2` in *first* memory location, then my address will be
 `00000000000000000001`(**20 bits**) and data in it will be:
 `00000000000000010`(**16 bits**).

Is it this way or am I missing something?

Thank you.

Comment: [In 16-bit microprocessors, why do we need a 20-bit address?](https://www.quora.com/In-16-bit-microprocessors-why-do-we-need-a-20-bit-address)

Comment: This might help:  [8086 Memory Segmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8086#Segmentation)

Comment: [How is a physical address generated in 8086?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4203921/104380)

Comment: My doubt is , Only the name of the address location is 20bit and the actual data is 16 bit?

Answer (score 3):

Each 20-bit physical address slot holds one 8-bit byte.  A 16-bit word takes 2 consecutive address slots.

Physical addresses (in original 8086) are 20 bits wide, *data* is (up to) 16 bits wide.

8086 does in fact have a 16-bit data bus, while 8088 had an 8-bit data bus and took 2 cycles to transfer a word but most of the rest of the chip is identical to 8086 right down to the transistor layout.

Address width and data width don't have to be related in any particular way.

---

**You don't store 20-bit linear addresses as data in memory**.  A pointer stored in memory is typically a 32-bit `segment:offset` pair.

You could compact a pointer down to 3 bytes, by normalizing the segment value so only a 4-bit offset is needed, or whatever other technique to remove some of the redundancy caused by the `seg<<4 + offset` real-mode address calculation.

Comment: So logically there's 16 bits but physically it's 20 bits?

Comment: My doubt is , Only the name of the address location is 20bit and the actual data is 16 bit?

Comment: @VijayachandranChettiar: No, logically linear addresses are 20 bits.  calculated from `segment_reg << 4 + offset`, where the offset is 16 bits.  Addresses and data are different things.  You don't store a 20-bit address in memory.

Comment: @VijayachandranChettiar: Your 2nd comment is correct: addresses are 20-bit, data is a multiple of 8 bits.

Comment: "while 8080 had ..." There's not too much to say about differing data widths when looking at the __20__-bit _addressbus_ of 8086 and the __16__-bit _addressbus_ of 8080. I think you ment to compare with the __8088__ instead where only the width of the _databus_ is the discriminating factor.

Comment: @Fifoernik: yes, I did mean to say 8088, thanks.  Good catch.